# Telerik Kendo ui grid displaying html cell instead of generated html control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the new Kendo UI grid from asp.net mvc 3.

I am having a table the table is generated automatically from a controller in asp.net mvc 3.

And display it with Kendo.ui grid.

However, I am having the html code inside of the cells instead of the html controls

Example:

it display in the cell: `<input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkb..` instead of an input, the code in the View is @html.input

or `<a href="/Admin/Edit">Edit</a> | <a href="/Admin/Details">Details</a> | <a href="/Adm` instead of a link ( code in the View is @Html.actionLink)

How can I make it encode html code ?

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendrierMatch").kendoGrid({

    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the Javascript code where you create the kendoUI grid?

Comment: this is my script:     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calendrierMatch").kendoGrid({

        });
    });

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The KendoUI Grid automatically encodes the content of the grid, that's why you get the text `<input type= ...` instead of the actual input controll.

You can disable the encoding for a given column with using the `encoded` options [(see documentation)](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/configuration.aspx):

> **encoded: Boolean(default: true)** Specified whether the column content
>   is escaped. Disable encoding if the data contains HTML markup.

So you need something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      //...
        columns: [
           {
               field: "Column containing HTML",
               encoded: false
           }
        ]          
      });
 });
```

Comment: Hi nemesv, thanks for your advice, I am using $("#grid").kendoGrid() to create my grid, the columns and datas are get directly from the table on the view ( with <thead> and <tbody> ), in order to use the encoded: false option, that means that for each time I need to declare all the columns for the table in the kendoGrid call ?

Comment: Based on the documentation in the current version there is no other way to turn the encoding off globally. So I'm afraid you need to specify all the columns, and turn off encoding individually...

Comment: I tried out the latest beta version, and I can get now the html rendered, however, cannot sort out the columns, even with the sortable: true option, I can see the icons up/down, but when clicking results nothing, have you seen anything similar ?

Comment: I haven't tried the beta yet, and I don't know why is the sorting not working, but I think this is then a different question.

Comment: Thanks anyway nemesv for your previous advice, it will help me out at one stage or another

Comment: @nemesv I am using angular Kendo grid. I tried your code but it is not helping me out.

Comment: @dotNetAddict the `encoded` setting is working you just need to supply it when you build your gridoptions in your controller: see this demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/OLUda

Answer (score 1):

in model binding kendo grid Razor Html Page use this code

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("GridName").Columns(col =>{
col.Bound(m => m.ID);
col.Bound(m => m.Name);
col.Template(@<text>
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode( item.Text))
    </text>);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the template feature  of kendo grid.

In the below code i have created a text box inside the cell of kendo grid.

```
 {
     field: "Total",
     title: "Total",
     width: "40px",
     template: "<input type='text'  class=\"quantity_total\"   id='txtTotal_${ItemId}'    
                name='txtTotal_${ItemId}' maxlength='8'    onkeypress = 'return 
                fnCheckNumeric_total(event,this.id)'  />"  
               
},
```